# How to get Digitalocean environment variable?

Tags: node.js, webpack, backend, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I set an environment variable in Digitalocean with token, but I don't understand how to use it in the code. I scrolled through the docs, but didn't get anything. Can you please tell which path I should write or anything else what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an environment function in your language of choice that searches the .env file or current global env and pull the variable that is available.

Example: for R, I can use `Sys.getenv("MY_SECRET")` to pull the variable from DO.

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in Digital Ocean using Functions over nginx runtime:

1. Require dotenv into main function
2. Process env into a const
3. Now you can use the environment variable

EXAMPLE

```
function main(event, context) {

  require('dotenv').config();
  const SECRET = process.env.VARIABLE_NAME;
 
}
```

Remember, is necessary to register the variable before access and use it.